# NHibernate doesn't delete an object

Tags: nhibernate

I load some objects using `ISession.Query<T>.ToList()`. Then I try to delete some of them in a loop using `ISession.Delete()`.

The same session is used for the query and the deletion but nothing is deleted. No SQL with DELETE statements is executed. No exception is thrown. Why are the objects not deleted? They also don't seem to be contained in any parent collections.

Comment: It would help if you posted the code which is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a transaction, you need to call `transaction.Commit()` otherwise you need to call `session.Flush()`.

If for some reason you are not using a transaction, you should be otherwise you can end up with inconsistent data in your database if some of the deletes fail.

Comment: With NHibernate you must use transaction all the time (select included)

Comment: @Kris-I - you don't *have* to but you *should*